# string Partial searchs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is a Table Name user-name
it contains multiple records

```
id       username  
1   Anil Kumar Maurya
2   Sunil Kumar Maurya 
3   Ranjeet Kumar Singh 
4   pinky Kumari Shahu
```

I Want To Search by
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE username  like  '%Anil Maurya%'`
but It does not find any record .............
How Can I search With a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wildcard in-between as well:

```
WHERE username  like  '%Anil%Maurya%'
```

Comment: @TrueUpDiamond . . . It is not intended to.  That is not the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 different like's since they are not side to side, for example;

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE username  like '%Anil%' and username like '%Maurya%'
```